# Samsung S21 camera2 API issue with near object

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera2

I am using Camera 2 API for capture image and it is working fine for other device than Samsung S 21 ultra 5G Android ver 11.
I am getting blurry image when capturing near object.

Comment: Same issue, any luck so far?

Comment: Not yet, Currently handling S21 users to open Native camera .

Comment: Updating patch solved issue!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I had luck today on my test S21. I updated the OS on the phone and it started working

Comment: What was your OS version before update and what OS is currently?

Answer (score 0):

Updating **patch** solved issue!!!!!!